# A probability with a dice

Tags: probability

A die is rolled repeatedly until it shows a six.

Let $A_n$ be the event that the first six appears on the $n$th roll.
And let $E$ be the event that the number of rolls required for the first six is even. Find $P(A_n), P(E).$

Well $$P(A) = \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)$$ and

$$P(E) = \sum_{n=1}^{\ \infty} P(\text{Six appears on } 2n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\ \infty} \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{2n-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)  $$

$$= \frac{6}{5} \times\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{\ \infty}\bigg(\frac{25}{36}\bigg)^{n} $$

$$= \frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\ \infty}\bigg(\frac{25}{36}\bigg)^{n} = \frac{36}{55}.$$

According to my textbook this is not the correct answer. The answer is 5/11, according to my textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$

Note the difference in the starting values of the indices.

Here, using the second and $x=\frac{25}{36}$ we have

$$\frac{1}{5}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^n = \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{~\frac{25}{36}~}{\frac{11}{36}} = \dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{25}{11}=\dfrac{25}{55} = \dfrac{5}{11}$$

You must have used the version where the index started from zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the second part using a method which sometimes comes in handy and avoids summing geometric progressions.

Let $P(E)$ and $P(O)$ be the probabilities that you throw the first $6$ after an Even/Odd number of throws.

Then $P(E)+P(O)=1$

also considering the situation after the first throw, either you have thrown a $6$ or not, and you need not to have thrown a $6$ to get a $6$ in an even number of throws. The extra throw changes the parity, so we get also $P(E)= \frac 56 P(O)$